# How to get all selected checkbox from a ExpandableListView in Android?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` that has groups and itens, each iten has a checkbox that can be selected and I want to know how can I iterate over all itens and get their values when I click the button.

So far I have created the list, I already can select the checkboxes and everything is going well, but I cant find a solution to get the values from the checkboxes when I click the button. This is like a questionary, when the user finishes picking his choices, he will submit the values.

I have a `MainActivity`, an `ExpandableListAdapter` that is my list adapter implementation and I have 3 xml, activity_main.xml, list_group.xml and list_itens.xml.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> listaDePerguntas;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listaDeRespostas;
private CheckBox check;   

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listaDePerguntas, HashMap<String, List<String>> listaDeRespostas) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaDePerguntas = listaDePerguntas;
    this.listaDeRespostas = listaDeRespostas;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listaDePerguntas.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return listaDeRespostas.get(listaDePerguntas.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return listaDePerguntas.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return listaDeRespostas.get(listaDePerguntas.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String resposta = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_itens, null);
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    text.setText(resposta);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String resposta = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_itens, null);
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
    text.setText(resposta);

    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCheckItem);
    //check.setFocusable(false);

    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), "Selected! - Question number: " + groupPosition + "answer: " + childPosition + "ischecked: " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

My `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ExpandableListView listView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;

    private List<String> perguntas;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> respostas;

    private Button enviarRespostas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    carregarDados();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, perguntas, respostas);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicou no:" + groupPosition + " item: " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicou no:" + groupPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    enviarRespostas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnviarRespostas);
    enviarRespostas.setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void carregarDados() {
    perguntas = new ArrayList<>();
    respostas = new HashMap<>();

    perguntas.add("Pertunta 1");
    perguntas.add("Pertunta 2");
    perguntas.add("Pertunta 3");
    perguntas.add("Pertunta 4");

    List<String> respostasPergunta1 = new ArrayList<>();
    respostasPergunta1.add("Sim");
    respostasPergunta1.add("Não");
    respostasPergunta1.add("Talvez");

    List<String> respostasPergunta2 = new ArrayList<>();
    respostasPergunta2.add("10");
    respostasPergunta2.add("20");
    respostasPergunta2.add("30");
    respostasPergunta2.add("40");

    List<String> respostasPergunta3 = new ArrayList<>();
    respostasPergunta3.add("Sim");
    respostasPergunta3.add("Não");

    List<String> respostasPergunta4 = new ArrayList<>();
    respostasPergunta4.add("10");
    respostasPergunta4.add("20");
    respostasPergunta4.add("30");
    respostasPergunta4.add("40");
    respostasPergunta4.add("50");
    respostasPergunta4.add("60");

    respostas.put(perguntas.get(0), respostasPergunta1);
    respostas.put(perguntas.get(1), respostasPergunta2);
    respostas.put(perguntas.get(2), respostasPergunta3);
    respostas.put(perguntas.get(3), respostasPergunta4);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //todo
}
```

}

And here are my 3 .xml files:

1) activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="437dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEnviarRespostas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2) list_group.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:paddingLeft="?
        android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3) list_itens.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItem"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?
            android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/listCheckItem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: are you able to maintain the state of checkbox that is selected when your list scrolls. From the first looks of code i think it would not work as expected.

Comment: The best way to do what you need is to create an array and then add the positions of items that are selected in your setOnCheckedChangeListener in that array to maintain the position. So if checkbox is checked add to array and its checked again to remove the check, you can also remove from array

Comment: Yes, the state of checkboxes are being maintained, I can expand and close the groups and the checkboxes keep their values.